# LDAP y alfresco

Tags: alfresco

He bajado la versión de alfresco *community 201605* y la instale en mi trabajo.

El problema está en que he revisado la doc y otros sitios buscando como configurar que se conecte al **LDAP** para que me cargue los usuarios del domino pero no logro encontrar la manera de hacerlo.

Entre las cosas que he visto me dicen que configure el archivo `alfresco-global.properties` pero no encuentro las propiedades a configurar que salen en la documentación. Ni tampoco la dirección `classes/alfresco/extension/Authentication/ldap` donde supuestamente debe estar un archivo de configuración.

Necesito ayuda con esto. Y agradecería que fueran bastante claros en la explicación.

Gracias de antemano.